# ui tabs youtube embed on iOS mobile

Tags: ios, youtube

Scenario:
JQuery UI Tabs - one of which has YouTube embed iframe code

Works fine on all browsers

In iOS mobile (iPhone/ iPad) the tab works but am not able to click on the YouTube - nothing happens

If I move the embed outside of the tabs it works fine in iOS mobile devices

Am using this version:
    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: update - this only happens if video is placed in 2nd or subsequent tabs. If embed is in the first tab then it works fine in iOS devices